# Merge Excel files with pandas in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm almost done with merging excel files with pandas in python but when I give the path it wont work. I get the error ''No such file or directory: 'file1.xlsx'''. When I leave the path empty it work but I want to decide from what folder it should take files from. AND I saved the file the folder 'excel'

```
cwd = os.path.abspath('/Users/Viktor/downloads/excel') #If i leave it empty and have files in /Viktor it works but I have the desired excel files in /excel 

print(cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
   if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
       df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel(r'/Users/Viktor/Downloads/excel/resultat/merged.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pd.read_excel(file) looks for the file relative to the path where the script is executed. If you execute in '/Users/Viktor/' try with:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.path.abspath('/Users/Viktor/downloads/excel') #If i leave it empty and have files in /Viktor it works but I have the desired excel files in /excel 

#print(cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  


df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
   if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
       df = df.append(pd.read_excel('downloads/excel/' + file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel(r'/Users/Viktor/downloads/excel/resultat/merged.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about actually changing the current working directory with

```
os.chdir(cwd)
```

Just printing the path doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

  - [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to find all the files
  - Use [`Path.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) if you want to include subdirectories
- Use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine the dataframes created with the [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) in the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

# path to files
p = Path('/Users/Viktor/downloads/excel')

# find the xlsx files
files = p.glob('*.xlsx')

# create the dataframe 
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, ignore_index=True) for file in files])

# save the file
df.to_excel(r'/Users/Viktor/Downloads/excel/resultat/merged.xlsx')
```